# FileWriter always recreated and reclosed() is it safer?

Tags: java, android, file, io, url-rewriting

I know either in **Android** or **Java desktop** We could write something into the file using this code below:

```
private void writeNow(){
   FileWriter fWriter  = new FileWriter(SDTool.getCurrentApplicationPath() + "/error.log", true);
   fWriter.write( dateFormat.format(date) + " :: " + n + "\n");
   fWriter.flush();
   fWriter.close();
}
```

but if every time I want to write i need to execute that method.
And the `FileWriter` object is always recreated, flushed and reclosed.
The more I used it, the bigger memory leak. Is there a safer method of doing this?

Comment: How often would you call `writeNow`?

Comment: usually i just putting that method whenever i tried to try-catch several lines of code. So if you asked, "How often?" I said, "very often.". @Marius

Comment: In that case, you should create in some higher scope. In Android's case, you usually release resources in `onPause`, and init them in `onResume`(or lazy load). I similar approach here.

Comment: @gumuruh it looks like you are creating your own logging mechanism.  Why not look at something that does this for you already like https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/
This should help having to manage resources.

Comment: @gumuruh Using a logging library will take care of any synchronization issues  when writing to the same file as well.  With multiple threads you could end up with strange interweaving.  The other alternative is to use a single FileWriter as a logger and make it available to globally.

Comment: so then should i put synchronized at the method statement above? @Beggs.... I prefer to use this one for a moment instead of adding more library in. :D

Comment: @gumuruh that would be a simple solution to the interleaving of multiple threads, however you need to be careful about synchronized because you could cause a performance bottleneck.  If interleaving isn't that big of an issue then I would leave it.